# "cannot open @@: No such file" building atf with Linaro/Libre Computer toolchain

Tags: gcc, arm

I'm attempting to recompile the bootloader for the Libre Computer AML-S905X-CC in this [git repo](https://github.com/libre-computer-project/libretech-builder-simple) per the listed instructions, on a Debian 11 virtual machine. The build is throwing some errors when it tries to build atf (Arm Trusted Firmware). This is the output from that segment of the build:

```
username@debian11:~/libretech-builder-simple$ PATH=/home/username/libretech-builder-simple/gcc/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-elf- make -C atf -j1 PLAT=gxl DEBUG=0 bl31
make: Entering directory '/home/username/libretech-builder-simple/atf'
  CC      bl31/bl31_context_mgmt.c
/home/username/libretech-builder-simple/gcc/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf-gcc: 1: cannot open @@: No such file
/home/username/libretech-builder-simple/gcc/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf-gcc: 2: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
make: *** [Makefile:1469: /home/username/libretech-builder-simple/atf/build/gxl/release/bl31/bl31_context_mgmt.o] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/username/libretech-builder-simple/atf'
```

These error messages seem very cryptic to me. `bl31/bl31_context_mgmt.c` doesn't contain '@@' anywhere. What is @@ and where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been due to the toolchain building aarch-64-elf-gcc for amd64 (64-bit OS), while I was on an i386 virtual machine (32-bit OS). Switching to a 64-bit OS got me past the error.